# Refresh DIV with a lot of html via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Sorry for the lateness, and the sloppiness about not posting code.

So here it works:
In the index page, there are some categories, which the user can use to filter between shown images.
When the user filters the images, I get the images and pass them via jQuery AJAX to my controller, where I get the new filtered images. 
Here is what the AJAX method looks like:
In the "filter_these" variable, the variables are stored.

```
$.ajax({

     'type': 'post',
     'url': '*controllername*',
     'datatype': 'html',
     'data': {'categories': filter_these}, 
     success: function(response){
         window.alert(response);
     }
});
```

In my controller, I get the new images, which are stored in a variable. While passing through in jQuery, the images are in "response" variable. Now I need to find a way to reload the images section of the page, with the new images. This could be easily done if I did not have to apply A LOT of HTML stuff around it.

So what I want to know is how do I reload that part of the page, with the new images.

I was thinking about echo'ing a page with those pictures in it, but I can't seem to find that out, while using Codeiginiter.

Or either echoes it in my controller, which is not a good way to work. Help would appreciate.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: " How can I do this without adding all the html with javascript/jquery?"  ...Are you asking how to program without using the programming language?

Comment: Probably you can use $.filter For example you can add to your images some classes ( or an object in a data attributes) as tags, then use filter to show only the images you need (user choose(. But for a better answer you need to give us more details and maybe post a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery function that loads (load_image.php) into some div.

```
$('#filter_id').click( function(){
                    // grabs some info so we know what the image is
        var aa = $('#image').val();
                    // clears the div before loading
            $('#div_id').empty();   
                    // loads the php page into the div                          
        $('#div_id').load('load_image.php?imagename='+aa);      

        });
```

load_image.php

```
   <php    
       $imagename = $_GET['imagename'];
    ?>

     <img src="/images/<?php echo $imagename;?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<div id="imagesContainer">
    <img src="image1.jpg" title="Fred" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" title="Dave" />
</div>
```

And use jQuery to show/hide the images using a text input box with the id "filter" (`<input type="text" id="filter" />`). This would use the text in the images' title attribute as what to filter on:

```
$('input#filter').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') { //If the filter is blank
        $('div#imagesContainer > img').show(); //Show all the images
    } else { //If the filter is not blank
        $('div#imagesContainer > img').hide(); //Hide all of the images to start with
        $('div#imagesContainer > img[title^="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show(); //Show the matching images
    }
});
```

Checkout this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59ngx/ (in this example you can search for Mario, Zelda or Sonic)